# My function for authentication in Flask, always allow user to enter restricted page

Tags: python, authentication, flask, web-applications

I've built a small web-app. This is how my home page looks like:

[image]

And this is a code that is responsible for handling this:

```
@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def greetings():
    error = None
    form = SecretsForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if form.your_secret.data == key:
            # Edit allowed (Add later.)
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
        else:
            error = "Looks like you are not allowed to go this way."

    return render_template("greeting.html", form=form, error=error)
```

I've set a global variable in my project which is equal to "qwerty". The problem is no matter what my input in the form is, or better yet if it's not even there, I can still access the page which I'm trying to put restrictions on. Any idea what could've gone wrong?

Comment: you are not preventing user to visit when it's not you, in the `else` block. are you handling this in html?

Comment: The thing is that the form shouldn't redirect you if you don't pass the correct input, but it does.

Comment: this means that `if form.your_secret.data == key` returns True. check if it returns true by using print statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay figured that out. The part in my html which was responsible for the form, had it's action set for uncorrent function, which rendered the forbidden template and didn't have a 'permission check' implemented in it. Always check which function is set for your form, so you don't end up like me staring at the monitor for too long trying to figure out what happened.